# PHP glob can't read tmp

Tags: php, wamp, glob, tmp

I am using wamp in win7, and I try to read c:\wamp\tmp by glob with php, but the result is an empty array

```
print_r(glob("C:\wamp\tmp\*"));
```

I can see any folder in `c:\wamp` except `c:\wamp\tmp`, and I make sure that folders has the same setting about read write...

Comment: Please check this[URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\t` is an escape sequence that means the <kbd>Tab</kbd> character. You have several ways to deal with it:

1. Escape it with another backslash.

   ```
   print_r(glob("C:\wamp\\tmp\*"));
   ```
2. Use single quotes instead of double quotes, since escape sequences aren't processed in single quotes.

   ```
   print_r(glob('C:\wamp\tmp\*'));
   ```
3. Use forward slashes instead of backslashes, since Windows allows either as a directory separator.

   ```
   print_r(glob("C:/wamp/tmp/*"));
   ```